# Does a father recite Baruch Shepetarani for an adopted son

Tags: halacha, blessing, children-parenting, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah, orach-chaim

According to some Poskim, a father should  recite a blessing named Baruch Shepetarani  when his son turns bar mitzvah age. My question is, should it be recited if a father adopts a son when that son turns bar mitzvah? What about the biological father?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rema in [OC 225:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.225.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) indeed writes a father should say the blessing for his son and such is the Ashkenazi custom. But note this is not a blessing with a source in the Talmud (rather it comes from the midrash), as such the more common custom is to say the blessing without God's name (see [there](https://dinonline.org/2017/11/17/baruch-sheptarani-laws-and-customs/) for further details).

**A number of *poskim* allow the father of an adopted child to say the blessing, without God's name, for their adopted son**

- R Ari Enkin, see [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/sinay/baruh-2.htm.), the reference to the Pri Megadim is oblique, the PM doesn't write about an adopted son, but about a father's responsibility to educate his son - something the father of an adopted child also has
- R Mordechai HaKohen, ([here](https://www.daat.ac.il/he-il/kitveyet/sinai/hakohen-imutz.htm?printview=true), using the same Pri Megadim)
- R Shlomo Aviner, quoted [here](https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%93-%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A5/)

**Other poskim write there is no obligation**, see e.g., [here](https://daat.org.il/shut/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A-%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%9F-%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A5/).

Comment: "allow the father of an adopted child to say the blessing, without God's name" This isn't much of a chiddush, since I can also say the blessing without God's name for anyone at any time. Or even for no one at all.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I agree it is not a big chiddush - but I hope it answers the question :->